# GDB error - not in executable format: file format not recognized

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I'm trying to use gdb with a simple hello world program, but having some trouble

**hello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello World");
   return 0;
}
```

I then compile using the following two commands:

`gcc -o hello.o hello.c`

`gcc -g -o hello.o hello.c`

But when I type `gdb hello.c` I get an error:
`"/home/myName/hello.c": not in executable format: file format not recognized`

Does anybody know why this may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run and debug the executable not the source file. And executables by common convention should not have .o as those are for intermediate objects. So try: `gcc -g -o hello hello.c && gdb ./hello`